# How to create new columns based on phrase existence?

Tags: python, pandas, text, extract, feature-detection

I want to create new columns based on phrase existence

This is my data

```
No   Body
1    Office software is already paid
2    Excel software is not paid yet
3    Power point software is already paid
```

I want to categorized by existence of some phrase, This is my code,

```
countries1 = df.body.str.extract('(software|is already paid)', expand = False)
dummies1 = pd.get_dummies(countries1)
df_1 = pd.concat([df,dummies1],axis = 1)
```

The result is

```
No   Body                                   software   is already paid    
1    Office software is already paid        0          1
2    Excel software is not paid yet         1          0
3    Power point software is already paid   0          1
```

What I expected is

```
No   Body                                   software   is already paid    
1    Office software is already paid        1          1
2    Excel software is not paid yet         1          0
3    Power point software is already paid   1          1
```

Whats wrong in my code? or maybe I don't use the right function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try using `extractall`:

```
df.assign(**df.Body.str.extractall('(software|is already paid)')[0]
              .str.get_dummies().sum(level=0))
```

Output:

```
   No                                  Body  is already paid  software
0   1       Office software is already paid                1         1
1   2        Excel software is not paid yet                0         1
2   3  Power point software is already paid                1         1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Numpy's `np.core.defchararray.find` to find the phrases

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

phrases = np.array(['software', 'is already paid'])

dummies = (find(
    df.Body.values.astype(str),
    phrases[:, None]) > -1
).astype(np.uint)

dummies

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=uint64)
```

---

You can then place the values into the existing dataframe

```
df['software'], df['is already paid'] = dummies
```

Or use `assign` and create a new copy with the required columns

```
df.assign(**dict(zip(phrases, dummies)))

   No                                  Body  software  is already paid
0   1       Office software is already paid         1                1
1   2        Excel software is not paid yet         1                0
2   3  Power point software is already paid         1                1
```